# React Router - url(#...) paths in SVG fail

Tags: svg, reactjs, react-router

I am not fully sure if I have narrowed down the issue correctly:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
 <Route path="/" component={AppComponent}>
  <IndexRoute component={StartComponent} />
  <Route path="page" component={PageComponent} />
 </Route>
</Router>
```

In `AppComponent` there is this JSX Render Template:

```
<div>
 <section className="content row">
   <ReactCSSTransitionGrouptransitionName="a">
    {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { key: pathname })}
   </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </section>
  <ul>
   <li><Link to="/">
    <svg version="1.1">
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0" stopColor="#56697B"/>
        <stop offset="1" stopColor="#7F99B4"/>
      </linearGradient>
     </defs>
     <ellipse cx="200" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    </svg>

   </Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/page">Page</Link></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

When I visit the Application everything is displaying correctly, when I click on the Menu point Page the Gradient vanishing from the SVG. When I go back to the Startpage it displays again.

- on Chrome it vanishes
- on Safari it turns black
- on Firefox all works

If I do `fill="red"` all works fine so my guess is, that `url(#grad1)` is not found after changing the page.

I did put the fill in the style, as an attribute, in the css - all behaved the same

I tried to Link via `url(/#grad1)`but this did't work in any Browser. I also tried to put all gradients in one SVG File and linked to it with `url(/img/helper.svg#grad1)`but that didn't work either.

Does Anybody know what is going on? Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `<base href="/" />` in your html?

Once I removed that, everything worked as expected.